# deep comparision: how does this code return false when values of 2 objects are not same?

Tags: javascript, logic

code:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
 if (a === b) return true;

  //2nd block
 if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
     b == null || typeof b != "object") return false; 

 let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);

 if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;

for (let key of keysA) {
 if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
 }

return true;
}

 one= {a:1, b:1};
 two = {a:1, b:5};
 console.log(deepEqual(one, two));  //returns false as expected
```

**1. can someone please explain what is the purpose of 2nd block? what is it doing?**

**2. which part deals with returning false when values in both objects are not the same? how is it being done?**

Comment: Eventually calling `deepEqual(a[key], b[key]` will be equivalent to calling `deepEqual(1, 5)` which will be false because of the first line.

Comment: hi, I'm sorry can you please step me through it? I'm having hard time visualizing this for some reasons? also, if i remove the "2nd block", how come it no longer returns the right values since that definitely has nothing to do with the first line (or may be it does?) where simple (a===b) is being checked?

Comment: the best way to step through these things is to add `console.log` everywhere. try adding one after declaring keysA and keysB, and one inside the for loop. 
(what I think is happening here is that it's assuming they are not equal because 1 and 5 are not objects, which returns false based on the typeof check)

Comment: @LShapz this actually makes sense. returning false based on the second check. just to be safe, I'm I correct to assume that given two different values, it first checks the first line and upon reaching `1===5`, the first line is skipped completely. control goes to the `2nd block` and a `false` is returned since `1` and `5` are not `objects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you have determines equality through process of elimination.  There are two tricky bits to this:

1. The 2nd block:

This essentially checks if the values a & b are not js objects (meaning that they do not have a deeper level -- the key-value pair -- to check for potential equality). If the values are primitive or null, then we can assume there's no way they can be equal and return false.

2. Recursion:

The line that checks if the values inside a & b (given a & b are objects) are equal is in the for-loop:
`!deepEqual(a[key], b[key])`
This says, take the value of a and b where key = key and check their equality.  In your example we check two cases:

the first:

```
a[a] = 1
b[a] = 1
deepEqual(1, 1) --> gets called for key = a
since 1 === 1 --> true gets returned
```

the second:

```
a[b] = 1
b[b] = 5
deepEqual(1, 5) --> gets called for key = b
since 1 !== 5 & 1 and 5 are not objects --> false gets returned
```

A step by step explanation through your code:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  // Checks for strict equality
  if (a === b) return true;

  //2nd block
  // If the values of a or b are not objects, then 
  // we've established that they cannot be equal, 
  // since they didn't return true at the above statement.
  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
    b == null || typeof b != "object") return false; 

  // Here a and b have to be objects, so they should have key-value pairs.
  let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);

  // Easy way to determine inequality, if they don't have 
  // the same number of keys, they must not be equal.
  if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;

  // Manually checks the value of each key in a
  for (let key of keysA) {
    // Eliminates objects for which the following is not true:
     //  1. key from a is also a key in b
     //  2. a recursive call on the values of a[key] and b[key] are equal
    if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
  }

  // After eliminating the cases where equality cannot be true, 
  // we are left with the equal case
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive function that when given an object will call itself with the values of those objects. So when you pass in `{b:1}, {b:5}` it will look at the keys and the call the function again just passing in the values if the keys match. So on the next iteration you call `deepEqual(1, 5)` which evaluates to false because it didn't return true for the `a===b` test, and one (or both) of the arguments wasn't an object (`typeof a != "object"`).

Here's the example with a single key and a console.log to help:

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
 console.log("deep equal called with:", a, b)
 if (a === b) return true;

  console.log("what types are a an b? ",typeof a , typeof b)
  console.log("return false if either is null or not object")
  //2nd block
 if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
     b == null || typeof b != "object") return false; 

 let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);

 if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;

for (let key of keysA) {
 console.log("lets see if", a[key], b[key], "are equal")
 if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
 }

return true;
}

 one= {b:1};
 two = {b:5};
 console.log(deepEqual(one, two));  //returns false as expected
```

If you are not used to looking at recursive functions, it's normal for it to take a while to sink in. They can be a little mind-bending even when they're not that complicated.

Comment: where in the code does it actually say "return false if 1,5 are not the same". all I see in the first line is that `return true` if both values are exactly the same. However, in this case `5` and `1` are not the same and yet it is able to correctly `return false` somehow? this is the real confusion. also please can you explain what is the 2nd block  exactly doing here?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. When you pass in two arguments that are not objects and the aren't `===` you get to the next block, which returns false if either is not an object. `typeof a != "object"`

Comment: yes that did it. it was definitely the second block returning false and not the first. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function opens with the following check:

```
if( a === b) return true;
```

This will cover all cases where the values are not objects, and the values can be equated directly. Objects however will have different references, and to compare them, you need to dig through them, value for value.

The second block:

```
if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
 b == null || typeof b != "object") return false;
```

This checks to see if the values are null or not an object. If at least one value is null or not an object, this block returns false. This is because of the first check not passing, we know that the values are not strictly equal, and if not objects or null, then they are not equal. Only if both values are objects will the code execute beyond this point.

The rest is checking if the keys and values of the objects are the same bu checking that the same amount of keys are set, that they are called the same, and then it recurses by calling it self to compare the values of the keys that are called the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function deepEqual(a, b) {
     // the line below checks whether two values are the same i.e 2 == 3 returns false;
     if (a === b) return true;

      /** This below if statement just checks to make sure that what is been passed 
    is an object . the "typeof" is what checks for it. when you run typeof on null values
  returns objects . so we must also check whether the value is null */

     if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
         b == null || typeof b != "object") return false; 

    // this puts into an array the object properties
     let keysA = Object.keys(a), keysB = Object.keys(b);

/** checks if the length of the array are the same. if they have the same number of properties the array length will be equal*/
     if (keysA.length != keysB.length) return false;

// this "let keys of keysA" was tricky for me but i figured it out
// it loops through the array and returns the value into the variable let
    for (let key of keysA) {
     /** the first checks whether keysB array includes the properties that key is returning from keyA. i would explain the "!deepEqual(a[key], b[key])" statement in the comments*/
     if (!keysB.includes(key) || !deepEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
     }

    return true;
    }

     one= {a:1, b:1};
     two = {a:1, b:5};
     console.log(deepEqual(one, two));  //returns false as expected
```

Now for the recursion statement !deepEqual(a[key], b[key]), remember that !means not . so if deepequal() returns true the if statements will evaluate . the array keysA and keysB just stored the properties of the object, but we need a way to compare the values of that object. 
Take for example we have objects benz and tesla

```
let benz = {
   color: "black",
   wheels : 4
}
 let tesla = {
   color: "red",
   wheels : 4
}
```

when we call Object.keys(benz) we get an array ["color", "wheels"]

To then find out the values of the object we run the code benz[keys]... keeping strictly with the code.

when the values get called. if the values are both equal returning true. this makes the recursive function to call itself again until the final value is gotten. 
i hope for all who read this will get it